# $(document).ready not firing?

Tags: jquery

Such simple code, why isn't it working?
When the page loads, it should display an alert box that reads "ready".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        Title
        </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert("ready");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Content
    </body>
</html>
```

I feel like it's something incredibly obvious, but I'm at a point where I can't think straight.

I've tried both in the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Code works fine in live version.

Comment: I updated the code, so it works. I removed the link now to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Where's your jquery ref?

```
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: 1.4.2 was a few revisions ago, 1.6.1 is available: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: I was thinking that, you know what's funny? The [source](http://jquery.com/) I copied from.

Answer (score 17):

I had this problem, but jQuery was referenced. I had accidentally written the previous script tag as a self closing tag when moving my javascript to an external file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wherever/whatever.js" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ /* not hit */ });
</script>
```

The external reference tag can't be self-closing. It should read `<script type="text/javascript" src="/wherever/whatever.js"></script>`

Comment: I was facing the same issue. Your answer did the trick for me. This is weird actually.

Comment: I did something more stupid, i forgot `}); </script>`

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to include jQuery, so `$` is undefined.

One glance at the JS console in chrome was all it took to figure out.  Whenever something JS wont go, your first check should always be the console to look for an error.  Usually this will tell you exaxtly what's up.

Comment: upvote, especially for the "console to look for error" bit.

Answer (score 2):

very simple you are trying creating a jquery object without linking to jquery.

### option one

link to jquery
use jquery 1.6.1 (currently the latest) 1.4.x is an older version.

see [here](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery)
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

### option two

alert(); can be called without jquery, so remove the `$(document).ready()` bit

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue, but I just had the same problem.
I thought I'd add this for other jquery newbies. I did not find this answer on Stackoverflow. 
In my case, I had to change from:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script src="./jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="./app.js"></script>
```

Looks like jquery needs the correct relative path specified. In my case, the script tags
are inside the index.html and the dir hierarchy is flat i.e

```
<dirname>
  -- index.html
  -- app.js
  -- jquery.min.js
  -- lodash.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include jquery before your jquery code...

Answer (score 0):

You aren't referencing the jQuery library anywhere, so `$(document).ready` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I had the vsdoc (Visual Studio intellisense script) included at runtime. Had to hide it at runtime like this:

```
@if(false){
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```